# Cannot determine what kind of differential equation this is and am unable to solve it

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

so the equation goes like this:

$dx+(e^y-x)dy=0$

i cannot separate this, nor am I able to find adequate substitution? Is someone willing to fill me in on what I'm missing?

Comment: Hint: think about dx/dy instead.

Comment: $e^{y-x}$ or $e^y - x$?

Comment: I've tried to invert it and got to this point:
x'=x-e^y
I was unable to proceed from here as this does not appear to be linear differential equation of first order

it's (e^y)-x

Answer (score 3):

$\frac {dx}{dy} = x - e^y\\
\frac {dx}{dy} - x= - e^y\\
e^{-y}\frac {dx}{dy} - e^{-y}x= - 1\\
e^{-y} x = -y + C\\
x = Ce^y - ye^y$

Comment: If you would be so kind, could you explain steps that you did to get line 4 from line 3? Originally I was also stuck on this step.

Comment: When I introduced $e^{-y}$ it was not to get rid of the $e^y$ on the right hand side.  That was a happy coincidence.  When you have $y' + P(x) y = G(x)$ an integrating factor of $e^{\int P(x)\ dx}$ will make the left hand side integrable.  i.e. $\frac {d}{dx}  \left(e^{\int P(x)\ dx} y\right) = e^{\int P(x)\ dx}y' + P(x)e^{\int P(x)\ dx}y$

Comment: Much appreciated!

Comment: And, from your nice solution, appears once more, Lambert function $y=W\left(-e^{-c} x\right)+c$